# Highcharts - display time data in tooltip

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts

I've got a chart that uses time data for both the X and Y axis. I'm able to get both axes to convert my millisecond data into `HH:MM:SS`. How do I get Y axis tooltip to display `HH:MM:SS` too? API suggests it's possible, however I'm unable to replicate.

> `tooltipValueFormat: String`
>
> Parallel coordinates only. Format that will be used for `point.y` and available in `tooltip.pointFormat` as `point.formattedValue` If not set, `point.formattedValue` will use other options, in this order:
>
> 1. `yAxis.labels`.format will be used if set
> 2. if yAxis is a category, then category name will be displayed
> 3. if yAxis is a datetime, then value will use the same format as yAxis labels

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.tooltipValueFormat

See my fiddle for example
https://jsfiddle.net/gramlich/jpnsujo8/1/

Not to further complicate things- I am doing this in a Django View, and passing the chart options via JSON to minimize my need for JS. If possible, I'd like to use a solution using only objects found in the Highcharts API; rather than resorting to writing my own Formatter function in JS.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, did my answer below helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pointFormat` passing the formatting string like:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{point.y:%M:%S}'
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w4f9suzb/